# Laravel 5 and Angular. Cors error when send data from frontend to backend

Tags: angular, laravel-5, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have problems sending data from a form by the Post method (I'm using Angular ***4***). I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ventas.dev/api/register. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I added the "Cors" to the application and thanks to that, using Postman I can create new users
[image]

I also reviewed the Laravel log but I have this information:[image]

I have uploaded my code to Gist so that anyone who wants to help me makes it easier.

https://gist.github.com/rickymuvel/806a0ebf37b182ea509d229642914d9f

Any help, thank you very much.

Comment: can you try adding content-type to your headers in angular? {'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

Comment: I just did it, but the same error appears.

Comment: are you sure http://ventas.dev/api/register has cors enabled?

Comment: Of course. You can review my code in: https://gist.github.com/rickymuvel/806a0ebf37b182ea509d229642914d9f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by installing the following library:

```
$ composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors
```

Add the Cors\ServiceProvider to your config/app.php providers array:

```
Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,
```

Add in Kernel.php file (app/Http/Kernel.php)

```
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```

That's all I needed. It works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to enable cors on your backend.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
private static $allowedOriginsWhitelist = [
      'http://localhost:8000',
    ];

    // All the headers must be a string

    private static $allowedOrigin = '*';

    private static $allowedMethods = 'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE';

    private static $allowCredentials = 'true';

    private static $allowedHeaders = '*';

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if (! $this->isCorsRequest($request))
      {
        return $next($request);
      }

      static::$allowedOrigin = $this->resolveAllowedOrigin($request);

      static::$allowedHeaders = $this->resolveAllowedHeaders($request);

      $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'       => static::$allowedOrigin,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'      => static::$allowedMethods,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'      => static::$allowedHeaders,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'  => static::$allowCredentials,
      ];

      // For preflighted requests
      if ($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS')
      {
        return response('', 200)->withHeaders($headers);
      }

      $response = $next($request)->withHeaders($headers);

      return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Incoming request is a CORS request if the Origin
     * header is set and Origin !== Host
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     */
    private function isCorsRequest($request)
    {
      $requestHasOrigin = $request->headers->has('Origin');

      if ($requestHasOrigin)
      {
        $origin = $request->headers->get('Origin');

        $host = $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost();

        if ($origin !== $host)
        {
          return true;
        }
      }

      return false;
    }

    /**
     * Dynamic resolution of allowed origin since we can't
     * pass multiple domains to the header. The appropriate
     * domain is set in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header
     * only if it is present in the whitelist.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     */
    private function resolveAllowedOrigin($request)
    {
      $allowedOrigin = static::$allowedOrigin;

      // If origin is in our $allowedOriginsWhitelist
      // then we send that in Access-Control-Allow-Origin

      $origin = $request->headers->get('Origin');

      if (in_array($origin, static::$allowedOriginsWhitelist))
      {
        $allowedOrigin = $origin;
      }

      return $allowedOrigin;
    }

    /**
     * Take the incoming client request headers
     * and return. Will be used to pass in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     */
    private function resolveAllowedHeaders($request)
    {
      $allowedHeaders = $request->headers->get('Access-Control-Request-Headers');

      return $allowedHeaders;
    }

}
```

Comment: What file should I modify or create?

Comment: @Ricky This will help you on how you can build your own custom middleware. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware